# jquery - call function in external js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, external

If I have this code in a file called custom.js:

```
var kennel = function(){this._init();};

kennel.prototype = {
    _init: function() {
        this.setListeners();
    },
    setListeners: function(){
        ...
    },
    getCats: function(){
        alert("Get cats");
    }
};
```

How do I call `getCats()` from some arbitrary html file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you would include the javascript by using the `<script>` tag, generally in the `<head>`, then after that you can create another `<script>` tag which you can place your own javascript code in that is specific to the page, and which uses the functionality made available by the included file. For example:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myKennel = new kennel();
        myKennel.getCats(); // alerts "Get cats"
    </script>
</head>
```

Also, the code you have posted has nothing to do with jQuery - it is plain old, vanilla javascript.

Answer (score 1):

This should be enough:

```
<script>
  var k = new kennel();
  k.getCats();
</script>
```

Here's a sample of it working: http://jsfiddle.net/NHaBb/
​